# Issue related to bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel but I need a very simple thing to be done. My carousel is placed in the bottom of the page and I want to stick to the 1st slide of the carousel until the user reaches this section. As soon as the user will reach the section,the carousel will start playing. I do not know how to achieve this. Please help me with ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you figure it out @Abhradip ?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

> The .slide class adds a CSS transition and animation effect, which
>   makes the items slide when showing a new item. Omit this class if you
>   do not want this effect.

So all you need to do is to add that class when the user scrolls to that element...

As in, for the example given on the link I mentioned above, the element with id='myCarousel' must be given the `.slide` class.

Hence, using the jquery, the code will be as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()>=($("#myCarousel").offset().top){
     $("#myCarousel").addClass("slide");
     //ANYTHING YOU WANT TO DO WHEN THE USER SCROLLS TO YOUR CAROUSEL. 
  }
 })
});


NOTE: CODE NOT TESTED.
```

You can do it like that.

Comment: I am sorry @Tirthraj Barot...But I fixed it in another way. See my answer.

Comment: Alright @Abhradip if you find this solution helpful or correct, you may mark it correct or vote it up..!

Comment: It did not work for me and you also said that the code was not tested at all. @Tirthraj

Comment: It was a concept. @Abhradip

Comment: I know @Tirthraj...and the concept is correct I think. But I cant mark it correct right now because It did not work for me. You posted it as code snippet so if I mark it as correct or vote for it,that would not be good for this community.

Comment:  absolutely correct.. I meant that if you find my concept correct, then you can approve it by voting it up.. Else it's fine buddy.. @Abhradip

Answer (score 1):

After doing quite a lot of research,finally I got this solution.I have mangaged to go back to the first carousel when I reach a specific portion.(Here the section where carousel does exist)

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        console.log($("#myCarousel").offset().top);
        if($(window).scrollTop()>=$("#myCarousel").offset().top-70 && $(window).scrollTop()<2450 )
        {
            var index = $('.slides li').index($('.slides li:first'));
            console.log(index);
            $('.flexslider').data("flexslider").flexAnimate(index);
        }
    })
});
```